# How can I use a for loop to make my code look less repetitive here?

Tags: python, for-loop

I meant to be drawing lines using graphics.py in python onto the graphics window.
My code here is very repetitive and i need to make it into a for loop which i dont know how to do.

```
win=GraphWin("Patch1", 100, 100)
win.setBackground("white")
l1=Line(Point(0,80),Point(20,100))
l1.setFill("red")
l1.draw(win)
l2=Line(Point(0,60),Point(40,100))
l2.setFill("red")
l2.draw(win)
l3=Line(Point(0,40),Point(60,100))
l3.setFill("red")
l3.draw(win)
l4=Line(Point(0,20),Point(80,100))
l4.setFill("red")
l4.draw(win)
l5=Line(Point(0,0),Point(100,100))
l5.setFill("red")
l5.draw(win)
```

Comment: This calls for a function.

Comment: have you made an attempt? `Point(0,80-i*20),Point(20+i*20,100)` as a hint

Comment: Try a `for` loop.

Comment: Why don't use a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum:

```
for p1, p2 in [(Point(0,80), Point(20,100)), (Point(0,60), Point(40,100), ...]:
    l = Line(p1, p2)
    l.setFill("red")
    l.draw(win)
```

The only thing that varies is the exact points used to generate the line; the rest can be abstracted into the body of the loop as shown.

I leave it as an exercise to figure out how to generate the list of `Points` less explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
win = GraphWin("Patch1", 100, 100)
win.setBackground("white")
for i in range(20,101,20):
    l = Line(Point(0,100-i),Point(i,100))
    l.setFill("red")
    l.draw(win)
```

You can also use a function here. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: How can i create a criss-cross design on graphics window using the same method ?